# Why can't I pass variable from component to service in this Angular 9 application?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a small application with Anular 9 and Angular Material. I have a list of items, each with an "Edit" button:

```html
<div class="item-name">{{node.item.name}}</div>
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="editItem($event, node.item.id)">Edit</button>
```

I am trying to get the item id in the component and the pass it to a service:

In the component I have:

```
public id: string;

editItem(event, id): void {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log("Item id is: " + id);
      this.id = id;
}
```

In the service I have:

```
getItemInfo(): Observable<any[]> {
    console.log(this.id);      
    if (typeof this.id !== 'undefined') {
        return this._http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl + this.id, httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError('getItemInfo', []))
            );
    }
}
```

The line `console.log("Item id is: " + id)` from the component outputs the expected result - the current item's id.

Yet, in the service `this.id` is `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question neither makes clear how the component `id` is related to service `id` nor where the `id` is used in the service. Could you please post more code?

Comment: `this` refers to the context your currently in. In typescript, this is most of the time the instance of the class where the method is defined. So if you mean to access `this` from the service and expect it to be the instance of your component, than that thought is wrong.

Comment: `this.id` in the *component* instance is **not** necessarily the same value as `this.id` in the *service* instance. Why doesn't `getTestInfo` take that as a parameter? This isn't really an Angular issue at all.

Comment: The context for both methods was completely different try to pass as an argument to youre service.

Comment: @Silvermind I am trying to set a value, in the *component*, for the `id`, then use it with that value, in the service, to retrieve some data.

Comment: Then pass that value to the service when you call the method (e.g. `this.theService.getTestInfo(this.id)`), but you have two **different** `this`s - `this` refers to the instance of the class in whose methods it's being used, it's not some kind of globally shared state. It's not at all clear why you expected that code to work.

Comment: How do you pass *any* argument to a function or method when you call it? Again, this isn't an Angular/TypeScript issue at all, this is basic JavaScript/OOP.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did `this.id = ''` and  `getTestInfo(id)...` in the service.

Comment: ...what? Why is the service calling its own method? What's the point of `this.id` if it's just an empty string? **Use the value the component passes.**

Comment: U need to pass the value to getItemInfo() from the component

Comment: Note that in the edit you've now removed you were trying to access `this.id` despite **not actually setting it**. I would strongly recommend a familiarity with basic JS usage before trying to add TS and Angular on top of that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, that addition of code was a "reply" to an answer that was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id isn't defined in the service, you could pass it inside the function like this:

In component:

```
import { YourService } from './servicePath';
...

constructor(public service: YourService ) { }

editItem(event, id): void {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("Item id is: " + id);
  this.service.id = id;
}
```

And then in the service have an id declared

```
id:string;

getItemInfo(): Observable<any[]> {
console.log(this.id);      
if (typeof this.id !== 'undefined') {
    return this._http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl + this.id, httpOptions)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError('getItemInfo', []))
        );
   }
}
```

Comment: The line `this.service.id = id` gives the error `Property 'service' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir You need to use the name you set in the constructor, did you add that line with your service?

Comment: Yes, the service is passed as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: Can you edit your question to what the code looks like with those lines? It's hard to tell what's missing atm

Answer (score 1):

In your Service, the property **id** is undefined since you don't set/pass it from your component. The above comment is correct to set a reference of the "id" from your component but I would suggest to change how you set the property **id**.

**The solution is to pass id in this way**

```js
getItemInfo(id): Observable < any[] > { // create parameter id

  console.log(id); // log the id for check

  if (typeof id !== 'undefined') { // update this.id to id
    return this._http.get < any[] > (this.baseUrl + id, httpOptions) // update this.id to id
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getItemInfo', []))
      );
  }
}
```

- *We create a reference **id** parameter directly from the method **getItemInfo** instead on service. Defining it on the service is actually ok but it's vulnerable where it can easily be change since it's public, and every time you set it through the service, it will keep the value unless you intend to do it for a reference to another service.*

**In your template, remove the *$event* in the editItem since it's no use and you're not using the event object in your code**

```html
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="editItem(node.item.id)">Edit</button>
```

**In your component, update the *editItem* method in the code below**

```js
editItem(id): void {
      console.log("Item id is: " + id);
      

    // you can call your service here or to another method
    // sample usage
    <YourService>.getItemInfo(id).subscribe(result => {
         console.log(result)
   })
}
```

- *You don't have to specify the stopProgation since you're not be doing any bubbling event behavior or redirection*

**NOTE:** Replace  with the actual name of your service

I hope I explain it.